# T-SQL -- faster way to do match for NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' used in CASE/WHEN statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization, sql-like, database-performance

I am looking for a potentially faster way to do this check:

```
NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

This checks to ensure all characters are numbers (see [description of T-SQL pattern](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/explanation-of-like-0-9))

Is there a faster way to do this in Microsoft SQL Server (T-SQL)?

The full context is as part of a CASE/WHEN statement in the select part of a vary large query:

```
Select    DATEADD(dd, CAST(CASE WHEN a.dateDuration NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' THEN a.Duration ELSE 1 END AS INT), a.StartDate) AS 'ourEndDate'
```

In the above, a is a table alias.  The column a.dateDuration is a nullable varchar column.  (The real names of entities have been replaced for proprietary reasons).

Indeed, variants of this are repeated in various "UNION ALL" operators, so if it could be made faster it could speed the query considerably.

The `NOT LIKE` operator is presumably relatively slow.

The version of the underlying database is SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Something like [`try_convert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) might be faster, but it won't handle strings with billions of characters and it would allow a negative sign (`-`) for `int` values. (See [performance rant](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).) Aside: The database implements the functionality. Everything you include about SSMS is just noise regarding a user interface.

Comment: There is a slight chance that `PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', textValue) = 0` might perform differently, since SQL might optimize out the `%`s in one case but not the other. Adding `COLLATE Latin1_General_Bin` might also yield a slight improvement, since it would avoid the potential overhead of case or accented characters equivalence. Both are speculation and would require testing.

Comment: What is the context here exactly? Is this in a `WHERE`? Checking if a value is a valid integer value will never be SARGable; a full scan will be required. If your data shouldn't contain characters other than digits, why not use a integer based data type?

Comment: There is no "faster way" to check if every single value matches a wildcard pattern or can be converted to a specific type. SQL Server has to try/check every value so it has to examine every row. Now, you could consider a computed column (e.g. `IntegerValue AS (TRY_CONVERT(int, col))`), index that, and pay that cost at insert time, but you have to pay for it.

Comment: Side note, I don't think there was an SSMS 15; the current version is SSMS 18, prior to that were 17 and 16 and then 2014 (which wasn't know as SSMS 15).

Comment: Should be pretty fast. Do you have a specific performance issue with it? (If yes, please give us a bit more context, as Aaron said, it could be needed to do the check at `INSERT` and `UPDATE` time and index the result to avoid table scans etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context performance of LIKE / NOT LIKE operator is almost for sure not a problem. If your query is slow consider first how many rows you are returning and if you are doing full scans on tables for looking interesing rows.

Here it looks like you are only trying to format/adjust your final result - if you consider SQL is too slow here you can do this processing on application server side as this is not a part of fetching data from disk.

If this is subquery please show entire query.